# Meu innerText não está funcionando

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Estudando eventos DOM</title>
    <style>
        div#area {
            font: normal 23pt Arial;
            background-color: blue;
            color: rgb(51, 214, 132);
            width: 14cm;
            height: 14cm;
            line-height: 14cm;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="area">
        Interaja
    </div>
    <script>
        var a = window.document.getElementById('area')
        a.addEventListener('click',clicar)
        a.addEventListener('mouseenter',entrou)
        a.addEventListener('mouseout',saiu)
        function clicar(){
            a.innerText('Clicou!')
            a.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
        }
        function entrou(){
            a.innerText('Entrou!')
            a.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
        }
        function saiu(){
            a.innerText('Saiu!')
            a.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) não é uma função é uma propriedade, então `a.innerText('Clicou!')` esta errado deveria ser `a.innerText = 'Clicou!'`

Comment: `element.innerText` não é uma função, é uma propriedade. Você deve atribuir algo a ela usando `a.innerText = "texto"`

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Segue seu código com as devidas correções.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Estudando eventos DOM</title>
    <style>
      div#area {
        font: normal 23pt Arial;
        background-color: blue;
        color: rgb(51, 214, 132);
        width: 14cm;
        height: 14cm;
        line-height: 14cm;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="area">Interaja</div>
    <script>
      var a = window.document.getElementById("area");
      a.addEventListener("click", clicar);
      a.addEventListener("mouseenter", entrou);
      a.addEventListener("mouseout", saiu);
      function clicar() {
        a.innerText = "Clicou!";
        a.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      function entrou() {
        a.innerText = "Entrou!";
        a.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
      function saiu() {
        a.innerText = "Saiu!";
        a.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```